# Convert contents of an XmlNodeList to a new XmlDocument without looping

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, xmldocument, xmlnodelist

I have Xml that I filter using XPath (a query similar to this):

```
    XmlNodeList allItems = 
xDoc.SelectNodes("//Person[not(PersonID = following::Person/PersonID)]");
```

This filters all duplicates from my original Persons Xml.  I want to create a new XmlDocument instance from the XmlNodeList generated above.  At the minute, the only way I can see to do it is looping through the list of XmlNode's and building an Xml string (as such):

```
        XmlNodeList allItems = xDoc.SelectNodes("//Person[not(PersonID = following::Person/PersonID)]");
        StringBuilder xml = new StringBuilder("<Persons>");

        foreach (XmlNode node in allItems)
            xml.Append(node.OuterXml);

        xml.Append("</Persons>");

        XmlDocument newXDoc = new XmlDocument();
        newXDoc.LoadXml(xml.ToString());
```

There has to be a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Out of interest, do you have to use XPath and do you have to use XmlDocument? LINQ to XML makes this sort of thing (and almost everything, actually...) simpler.

Comment: I'm not precious about it being loaded into an XmlDocument.  In actual fact what I use the output of this is for populating a DataTable.  So it's string XML that I'm really interested in.  I did convert the foreach to Linq but it seemed to perform as slow as the foreach above :-|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're happy to convert it into LINQ to XML, it's really simple:

```
XDocument original = ...; // However you load the original document
// Separated out for clarity - could be inlined, of course
string xpath = "//Person[not(PersonID = following::Person/PersonID)]"

XDocument people = new XDocument(
    new XElement("Persons",
        original.XPathSelectElements(xpath)
    )
);
```

You definitely don't need to convert each node into a string and back. You don't need to with `XmlDocument` either, but it wouldn't be quite as simple as with LINQ to XML :)

Comment: Getting an error using this approach Jon "Non white space characters cannot be added to content.".  The code I'm using is as follows:   string outputXml = null;
            using (var nodeReader = new XmlNodeReader(xDoc))
            {
                nodeReader.MoveToContent();
                var original = XDocument.Load(nodeReader);
                string xpath = "//Person[not(PersonID = following::Person/PersonID)]";
                XDocument people = new XDocument("Persons", original.XPathSelectElements(xpath));
                outputXml = people.ToString();
            }

Comment: NOTE: this worked:  XDocument people = new XDocument(new XElement("Persons", original.XPathSelectElements(xpathFilterDups)));

Comment: @RobMcCabe: Whoops, yes, forgot about making the root an explicit XElement. Fixed :)

Answer (score 1):

With `XmlDocument` you can use

```
XmlDocument doc2 = new XmlDocument();
doc2.AppendChild(doc2.CreateElement("Persons"));
foreach (XmlElement person in allItems)
{
  doc2.DocumentElement.AppendChild(doc2.ImportNode(person, true));
}
```

Comment: I was hoping to avoid looping through each XmlElementNode if possible to improve efficiency.

Comment: I'm not sure how you propose creating a new document from elements in an existing document without reading all the elements from the existing document,  The only part of this that's likely to be slow is the evaluation of the XPath expression.

Comment: That was the purpose of posting this question :-)  to work out if it was possible.  I'm already using an approach similar to what you've suggested.  The XPath actually evaluates reasonably quickly.  I have over 4000 elements to parse in the xml so the for loop is really quite slow.  Was hoping to avoid it :-\

Comment: I don't think there is a way to avoid the loop but using AppendChild on an ImportNode instead of a StringBuilder and OuterXml should be more efficient.